# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web forms combined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using a combined ASP.NET application.
The first website was made with webforms and the added functionality (secondary) website is made with MVC 5.

I have one page that I need in both websites and this was made in Webforms (.aspx). I want to use the same functionality in the MVC website.

I made the following:

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**View:**

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<iframe src="~/Webpages/test.aspx" frameborder="0" height="550" width="900"></iframe>
```

The webforms page uses a MasterPage.
If I am in the MVC website I will use a blank MasterPage.

This is working well but I don't know if this is the best solution. The webforms page is loading a bit slower than the original page.

Answer (score 1):

You are not need to use iframes in this situation. Just you can copy your design in view, logic in controller.. Then you can get your solution.. I will prefer you Razor view.